# Read a config file without source in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to read a value from my config file and substituting it in my other file named test.env.

config file has key and value pair as below:

```
SERVER_NAME=testserver
HOSTNAME=localhost
```

test.env file

```
echo "server name is ${SERVER_NAME}"
echo "Server is running on host ${HOSTNAME}"
```

Would it be possible to automatically assign a variable in test.env file.

Expected output will be as follows:

```
echo "server name is testserver"
echo "Server is running on host localhost"
```

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: I am using a bash shell

Comment: Are you trying to permantly modify `test.env`? Or print out its contents but with the variables substituted (based on config file)?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `source`?

Comment: @dan Yes, I permanently want to modify the test.env file with actual contents from config file

Comment: @Cyrus Due to security reasons I am trying to avoid use of source

Comment: `source <(sed -E '/^(SERVER_NAME|HOSTNAME)=[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/!d' file)`?

Comment: The linked duplicate has an accepted answer where one of the branches does not use `source`.

Comment: That said, insofar as you care about security, I **strongly** recommend reading your variables into an associative array, not directly into environment variables. There are a _lot_ of environment variables where an attacker can leverage control of that variable's value into arbitrary code execution later (think `LD_PRELOAD`, `PATH`, or even variables that be eval'd by a shell during prompt formatting), so when you care about security, you should either put variables read from an untrusted source into an associative array or put a lowercase prefix on the front of their names

Comment: (a lowercase prefix because POSIX requires that standard-defined tools use only all-caps environment variables to modify their behavior, whereas names with lowercase characters are reserved for application use, and POSIX-compliant tools must not modify their behavior based on same -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)